# XPath Function to query across 50 XML Files?

Tags: xml, search, xpath, notepad++

Fellow Forum Members,

I have 50 XML files and I need to be able to perform a XPath Query accross all 50 XML Files. I am using **NotePad++** and an **XPath Evaluator Plugin**.  I need help authoring a XPath expression that queries all 50 XML files. All 50 XML files are located in `C:\Root\Test\`

All I need is help in figuring out the correct function to use in my XPath expression so that it searches through all of the XML files located in the TEST folder. I know that **NotePad++** can perform a search through all files as a group. However, I need to make this work using me **XPath Evaluator plugin**. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Um, I could be wrong, but XPath expressions seem to be designed to only evaluate against the currently loaded DOM, and not execute across a folder full of files. What plugin do you use that extends XPath expressions to multiple files? (I'm seriously interested - I wrote a tool at work that searches a folder full of XML files for specific information, and it works by opening each file and then performing an XPath search to see if the content is found. If there's a way to do it more simply, I'd be interested.)

Comment: In XPath 2.0 you can use the `collection()` function (http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-collection) to do this. I highly doubt your plugin supports XPath 2.0 though. Saxon is very easy to run from the command line and could easily handle your requirements. If you're interested, let me know and I'll give an example as an answer.

Comment: Daniel and Ken I am using the NotePad++ plugin downloadable in the following link: http://code.google.com/p/xpatherizernpp/downloads/list               It makes no mention if it complies with XPath 2.0.  I have tested the COLLECTION command and it seems not to like it. Therefore, it's probably not XPath 2.0.  Does anyone out there know what XPath function might possibly work with my Notepad++ XPath Evaluator plugin. I am assuming there is a function that I can substitute for the COLLECTION command.

Answer (score 2):

You need an `XPath 2.0` (or `XQuery 1.0`) processor that supports the `collection()` function and gives access to directories.

Download `Saxon` and do something like:

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query -qs:"collection('file:///Root/test?select=*.xml')//x[y='z']"
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. Is the download link below the correct one?   http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/

Comment: Yes, latest maintenance release though is 9.5.1.4.